# iOS 7 - header HTTP header request?

Tags: httprequest, request-headers

I am not really familiar with iOS 7, and I am trying to build an application which needs to set values and send the HTTP request header to my server. However, it seems that my server did receive the value I sent which is the token I got from FacebookSDK (I'm using FacebookSDK to log in already, and now I got the token in my hand), because I got the notification that the server didn't see it as a header HTTPReques. Here is my code:

```
- (void)postToken
{
// Get the token from Facebook
NSString *token = FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.accessToken;

// Create the server name
NSMutableString *server = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[server appendString:@"*My server website here*"];

// URL Request and initialization
NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:server]];

[postRequest setValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"Token"];

// Set the request's content type
[postRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[postRequest setValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"Token"];

// Designate the request a POST request and specify its body data
[postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// The delegate provides receives notification
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:mutableReq delegate:self];

self.connection = connection;

[self.connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[self.connection start];

if (self.connection) // if connect successfully
{
    NSLog(@"Connection Success!");
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:server]; // Initialize url
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; // Initialize request
    NSURLResponse *server_response = [[NSURLResponse alloc] init]; // Initialize response

    self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [self.receivedData appendData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&server_response error:nil]]; // Receive data synchronously
    [self connectionDidFinishLoading:self.connection];
}
else
    NSLog(@"Connection Failed!");
}
```

the output is "Connection Success!" and the output contains my token (so I don't wanna post it here) and the message from the server that tells me no token was provided, which means it can talk to the server but the server didn't recognize the token as the header HTTP request. Can anyone help me out on this, please? Thanks in advance!